# Clear input in stateless React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I want to implement an X icon inside Input component that will clear the input field. I can easily do it if I control the state. But is it actually possible with stateless component?
I use react-semantic-ui, their stateful components have auto controlled state.

So I want to create an input that can be used like this:

```js
//Controlled
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value:''
  }

  onChange = (event, props) => {
    this.setState({value: props.value});
  }

  onClearInput = () => {
    this.setState({value: ''});
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
        <MyInput
          clearable
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          onClearInput={this.onClearInput}
        />
      )
  }
}
```

Or

```js
// Uncontrolled
class App extends React.Component {
  onChange = (event, props) => {
    doSomething(props.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <MyInput
          clearable
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
      )
  }
}
```

In the second example, `clearable` feature will not work because we're not controlling the value.

`MyInput` can be implemented like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Input } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import ClearIcon from './ClearIcon';

function MyInput(props) {
  const prepareProps = {...props};
  if (props.clearable) {
    prepareProps.icon=<ClearIcon onClick={props.onClearInput} />;
    delete prepareProps.clearable;
  }
  delete prepareProps.onClearInput;
  return (
    <div className="my-input">
      <Input {...prepareProps} />
    </div>
  );
}
...etc.
```

My problems:

1. `clearable` feature must work in both controlled and uncontrolled manner.
2. `clearable` feature should not require a handler. It would be nice to just provide a prop and handle the render and behavior of the X button under the hood.

I don't see any way to make this work. Any ideas?

Comment: Why does it have to work on uncontrolled inputs?

Comment: @trixn, why not? :-)
I just want to create a versatile component without forcing people to use it in any specific way. So if you just put `<MyInput clearable />` in your app you will have an input with X button that will just work out of the box. I don't think it's possible, but maybe I'm missing something. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: Yeah but if **you** write the component that gets used by somebody else, why should they care if it internally uses a controlled or an uncontrolled input? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I agree with @trixn. You can use render props https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html, this will let the person using your component consume your controlled props into their own view or just control the input. The only other scenario I can see, is that the user of your component will have to pass you a `ref` to their input.

Comment: Right, people should not care what I do internally. But they should be able to use the component both controlled/uncontrolled way. The problem is that I cannot control `value` internally because then users won't be able to set their own `value`. On the other hand, if I don't control the `value` I cannot clear it.
@pkuzhel I don't see how render prop can help me here. Can you explain, please?

Comment: Take a look at this awesome component: https://github.com/paypal/downshift. The dev uses controlled props in a way that gives full freedom to its consumer.

Comment: Why should users not be able to set the value if the underlying input is controlled? If they use your component they can't use it in a controlled/uncontrolled way because you already made that decision for them. Of course you can update your internal state of your controlled input to set a value given through props even in a controlled input.

Comment: You can use 'ref' property to achieve this. You can see it here in action https://jsfiddle.net/sajankumarv/kfd0yyyw/3/

Comment: @sajankumarvijayan Can you finish your example and make Clear button work?

Comment: @Andrey Can you check now https://jsfiddle.net/sajankumarv/kfd0yyyw/5/

Comment: @sajankumarvijayan, it works, thank you. Unfortunately, it doesn't help me because I'm using SemanticUI Input and it won't clear like that.

Comment: @Andrey I believe you cloned the SemanticUI source, I would suggest dig the source code a little and modify the code a little as you like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allowing the user of your component to set the value via props and still being able to clear the input can be easily achieved, e.g. like this:

```
class MyInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: props.value || ''};
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        const { onChange } = this.props;
        this.setState({ value: event.currentTarget.value });
        onChange && onChange(event);
    };

    handleClear = () => {
        const { onClearInput } = this.props;
        this.setState({ value: "" });
        onClearInput && onClearInput();
    };

    render() {
        const { value } = this.state;
        const { clearable, onChange, ...inputProps } = this.props;

        const clearIcon = clearable && <ClearIcon onClick={this.handleClear} />;

        return (
            <div className="my-input">
                <Input value={value} icon={clearIcon} onChange={this.handleChange} {...inputProps} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

You could even make it more composable by using an hoc or render props as proposed by @pkuzhel.

Look at [this codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nnn5q91wo4) to see it in action.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. Users of such component will not be able to have full control of the value. For example try to use this component in controllable manner and set `onChange` to empty function. You would expect the input to stay empty when typing, but it will still show you the typed characters.

Comment: @Andrey No it will not. Look at the line `<Input value={value} icon={clearIcon} onChange={this.handleChange} {...inputProps} />`. If you provide a `value` prop from outside it will override the value. It is fully controllable from outside and clearable. I added a codesandbox example.

Comment: @Andrey If you test it you will see it does exactly what you want.

Comment: you changed your initial code and made my comment irrelevant. Great. Your code still doesn't solve my problem #2 because you're forcing users to implement their own `onClearInput`.
I managed to solve this using `uncontrollable` lib, will post the answer later.

Comment: @Andrey It‘s a pitty I wasted my time to provide you with the correct solution when you refuse to ubderstand it. A controlled input is not allowed to clear itself. The state of the parent must at any time be the value of the input. So the parent **must** clear the input itself, otherwise the input switches from controlled to uncontrolled. What you call „forcing“ in reality is what the user wants if he himself takes control of the value. That‘s why it is called **controlled**. Please do not ask questions in the future that you think you know the solution to safe other peoples time.

Comment: I will accept your answer so you don't feel like you wasted your time. You would waste it anyways :-) Thanks for your input bro

Answer (score 0):

@Andrey

Would you try this below code? and let me know if that resolves your issue.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Input, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class App extends Component {
  clear = () => {
    console.log(this.inputRef.target.value);
    this.inputRef.target.value = '';
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Input placeholder='Search...' onChange={(input) => {input.persist(); this.inputRef = input}} />
        <Button onClick={this.clear}>Clear</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```